# window.open location=no does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following that opens the window fine. Most of the elements like the navigation bar and buttons are gone. But the url address field is still not disappearing. What gives?

```
window.open('www.mysite.com','Window','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=500,height=450');
```

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons, modern browsers will always display the address bar.

Setting `location=no` makes it read-only.

For the same security reasons, there is no workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is browser dependant and will not work on all browsers, unless i am mistaken.